# Link becomes white in some browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm helping my brother to set up a site for his business, and I've hit a snag. A hyperlink becomes white, and thusly invisible, in some browsers. What's even more puzzeling, it's white in Firefox, but not while browsing in porn mode, [se this screenshot. (1)](http://postimg.org/image/s0jb5yb8f) (This made me think the problem was gone, but due to faulty flushing of cache.) The link works, and if you know it's there you can click it (or tap it if on a tablet or phone), but you can't see it.

HTML for index.html (2)

```
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil.css">
        <title>Albins glass och delikatesser</title>
</head>
<body>
        <img alt="Albins glass och delikatesser" src="bilder/albinsglass.gif" style="width: 320px; height: 175px; display: block; margin: 0 auto;"/>
        <div class="meny">
                <ul class="meny">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Hem</a></li><li><a href="sortiment.html">Sortiment</a></li><li><a href="turlista.html">Turlista</a></li><li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <p>V&auml;lkommen till <i>Albins glass och delikatesser</i>, din lokala glassbil med god svensk kvalitetsglass fr&aring;n <i>Engelholms Glass</i> och smakrik lokalproducerad ostkaka!</p>
        <p>Glassen tillverkas i &Auml;ngelholm av det svenska familjef&ouml;retaget Engelholms Glass. De satsar p&aring; h&ouml;gsta kvalitet och tillverkar gr&auml;ddglass med de b&auml;sta r&aring;varorna. <a href="http://www.engelholmsglass.se" target="_blank">L&auml;s mer om Engelholms Glass h&auml;r.</a></p>
        <p>Ostkakan kommer fr&aring;n <i>Stellas Ostkaka</i> i Pil&aring;s! <a href="http://www.stellasostkaka.se" target="_blank">L&auml;s mer h&auml;r.</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS for the site (3)

```
body {
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
        font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
}
a:link, a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, a:active {
        color: #FF9595;
}
.meny a:link, a:visited {
        display: block;
        width: 120px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #00AEEF;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.meny a:hover, a:active {
        background-color: #0066CC;
}
b {
        font-weight: bold;
}
c {
        text-align: center;
}
i {
        font-style: italic;
}
p {
        margin: 10px;
        overflow: visible;
}
div.meny {
        margin: 10px auto 25px;
        width: 536px;
}
ul.meny {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
}
.meny li {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
}
```

The site in question (4) (in swedish)
http://www.albinsglass.se

Note, due to limitation on new accounts, I can apparently not include more than two links. [Here's a link to a pastebin with the four links i mentioned.](http://pastebin.com/46Asnxvq)

LLAP!

Comment: once you've visited the link you are hitting this CSS selector `.meny a:link, a:visited {` which states the color should be white.(PS if you include the HTML, CSS in this question we won't need to link to it)

Comment: Is porn mode incognito mode aka nothing is saved?

Comment: Yeah it is "In private" mode which browses in its own context, not "knowing" if  you've visited a link in the regular mode browser.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've visited the link you are hitting this CSS selector `.meny a:link, a:visited {` which states the color should be white.

You can alter the CSS for this to whatever color you want, or provide a separate CSS rule.

I would change this:

```
.meny a:link, a:visited {
        display: block;
        width: 120px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #00AEEF;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

to:

```
a:visited{
    color:#990099;/* Change this to whatever color you want your plain links to be */
}
.meny a:link, .meny a:visited {
          /*  ^^^^^--This specifies that only links *within* your menu are styled here */
        display: block;
        width: 120px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #00AEEF;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I see now that I omitted the class after the comma.